# Comparing ranges in Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

Why does this equation return false

```
(0..9) === (0..9)
=> false
```

While this equation returns true...

```
5 === 5
=> true
```

And this equation is also true?

```
(0..9) == (0..9)
=> true
```

What am I missing about ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Range` class redefines the `===` operator to check if the argument on the right is within the range per http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

[Range#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) documentation says:

> Returns true if obj is an element of the range, false otherwise.
>   Conveniently, === is the comparison operator used by case statements.

The range (0..9) is not an element of the range (0..9), which is why `(0..9) === (0..9)` is false.

[Range#==](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D) documentation says:

> Returns true only if obj is a Range, has equivalent begin and end
>   items (by comparing them with ==), and has the same exclude_end?
>   setting as the range.

The start and end items of the ranges (0..9) and (0..9) are the same, which is why `(0..9) == (0..9)` is true.

Comment: An example of use in a case statement: `case n; when (0..32); <do something>; when (33..64); <do something else>: end`.